# Deploy django en hosting

Tags: django, deployment

Hola que tal a todos!!

Estoy avanzando en el desarrollo de aplicaciones con django, y ha llegado el momento de pasar quizá la mayor prueba: el deploy en un servidor web. Como me interesa aprender sobre la marcha, mi intención es ir revisando el procedimiento para hacer un deploy en un hosting, no digo la marca pero empieza con azul en inglés jejeje, estoy siguiendo un tutorial pero hay algo que no me permite visualizar la pantalla "It Works" en el navegador.

Tengo lo siguiente:

1) Usando Putty para conectarme con el servidor, abrí una carpeta en public_html para probar, se llama myenv

2) Estando dentro de `myenv/`

`#virtualenv myenv/`

aquí ya aparecen las carpetas `bin/`, `include/`, `lib/`

3) Se activa el entorno virtual

`#myenv]# source bin/activate`

4) instalo django 1.9 y gunicorn

`# pip install django==1.9 gunicorn`

5) creo un proyecto django en blanco

`#django-admin startproject myproject`

6) me cambio a la carpeta myproject con `cd myproject`

7) genero la migración y creo un superusuario

`#python manage.py migrate`

`#python manage.py createsuperuser`

8) Aquí es donde ya tengo el problema, al levantar gunicorn

`#gunicorn myproject.wsgi:application --bind 50.xx.xx.133:8000`

me aparece lo siguiente:

`[INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.6.0`

`[INFO] Listening at: http://50.xx.xx.133:8000`

`[INFO] Using worker: sync`

`[INFO] Booting worker with pid: 6041`

Que es al parecer la señal de que está en servicio gunicorn, pero al momento de ir al navegador y teclar la IP con el puerto, no se conecta, enviando el mensaje de que tarda mucho la conexión.

¿Debo de modificar algo al momento de levantar gunicorn?

Les agradezco de antemano su apoyo, con este paso ya me siento cada vez en confianza con django. Quedo atento a sus comentarios y respuesta. Un saludo.

Gustavo.

Comment: No deberías tener que modificar nada mas, pero si no dices la "marca" de tu proveedor de hosting va a ser muy complicado que podamos ayudarte. Si es posible, indica que tipo de servidor estás usando: dedicado o VPS. Tal vez sería más conveniente para ti, pedirle a tu proveedor que te permita usar esos puertos.

Comment: Muchas gracias @toledano, pues de hecho el hosting que utilizo es de Bluehost, del que ya tengo más de un año, lo contraté por que necesitaba en ese momento una aplicación web para PHP, que se desarrolló en cakephp, que sinceramente me atrajo pero la curva de aprendizaje es mayor que con python.

Answer (score 0):

El 'Hosting Azul' no es muy compatible si es un hosting compartido, ademas esta optimizado para hospedar un CMS PHP. Te recomiendo utilizar un VPS. Yo en lo personal desistí de instalarlo ahí porque quería mas control sobre mi servidor.

DigitalOcean ofrece droplets económicos para instalar aplicaciones como Django, de hecho ya tiene una imagen de Django lista, también tiene tutoriales completos en como instalarlo en uno de sus servidores para producción. Y sus precios son bajos también.

Comment: y aquí https://education.github.com/pack puedes obtener crédito para DigitalOcean, Microsoft Azure y muchos otros beneficios como estudiante :D

Comment: Gracias @fermin-arellano por tu comentario, entonces tendré que revisar la oportunidad de usar un droplet, he revisado información y se que es más natural el proceso del deploy, se que las tecnologías se han desarrollado demasiado, pero entonces conviene tener para un sitio digamos con joomla, moodle, wordpress, o para aplicaciones PHP un servicio como el de BlueHost, mientras que para aplicaciones con django sería conveniente tener en DigitalOcean.